# Commit a single file without working copy

Tags: svn

I have a file in the repository and I want to commit a new revision of the file.

Is there a way to do that without checkout of the repository or the folder of this file (I want something like SVN import, but over an existing file and without losing the file's history).

is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply checkout the directory in which that files lives. Then you **copy** the modified version of your file into that directory, and upload that file from there, like:

```
svn checkout repo-url target-dir --depth empty
cd target-dir
cp /whatever/changed-file .
svn up changed-file
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and if it works mark this as answer.

Comment: My SVN skills are bit rusty, but I hope it will work for you.